# What are the abilities of the Pegasus Galaxy's species, the Wraith?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Can the Wraith life-suck human clones/animals?  It seems throughout the series that Wraith only feed on humans, while the bug counter-parts (I think) feed on other animals.

Are humans the more tasteful or the most nutritious source to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only humans in the long run.  From [Joseph Mallozzi's blog](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/december-17-2008-yes-i-think-ill-have-the-everything/) (executive producer and writer for *Stargate*):

> Halo Luver writes: “1. Are Wraith capable of drawing nourishment from
>   other rational creatures besides humans? Perhaps Asgard or Goua’ld
>   symbiotes?
>
> 2. Does mass have an effect on how much nourishment a wraith takes from its victim?”
>
> Answers: 1. Although a wraith is able to derive some nourishment from
>   other creatures (like, say, an Asgard), in the long run it will need
>   to feed on humans to ensure its survival. 2. Good question. I think
>   it’s not so much mass but maturity.

On the note about tastiness, more is revealed in 1x18, ["The Gift"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gift):

> The Wraith scientist that accidentally gave Teyla and her ancestors the ability to sense the wraith was looking for a way to "make the feeding process more efficient.".  This was interpreted by McKay as "more tasty".